# Mapping Forge Viewer button to external buttons

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am hosting Forge Viewer as a component in my own GUI. I am wondering if I can map Forge Viewer buttons to external buttons in my own GUI.

An as example, instead of clicking on the model browser button in Forge Viewer, I want to be able to click on a button in my own GUI in order to see the tree view of the loaded model in forge viewer.

Such feature is already implemented in viewer.autodesk.com for model browser button, and I am wondering how I can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing. These default controls are usually nested inside extensions that house the ui for that functionality. However you can get any extension by name after initaliazing the viewer using [getExtension](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getextension-extensionid-callback) You now have a reference to the extension which you can [control](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/ModelStructureExtension/)

Please try this is browser console:

```
let ext = null
let gotExtension = function(extension){
    ext = extension
}
let openEvent = function(extension){
    extension.activate();
}
let closeEvent = function(extension){
    extension.deactivate();
}
NOP_VIEWER.getExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure', gotExtension);
openEvent(ext);
```